# React onclick setState not working with arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a component. I want to calculate some numbers here. When click the button it's not working with `onClick={() => setEarned(calculateEarned)}`. But when I change it like `onClick={setEarned(calculateEarned)}` it works but one time and when the page loaded. So I'm stack. Where is the problem I couldn't find.

```
import { Button, PrimaryButton } from "../../components/Button/Button"

export const CryptoCalculator = () => {
    const [earned, setEarned] = useState(0)

    function calculateEarned() {
        console.log('hit')
        return 1
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <PrimaryButton
                title="Calculate"
                onClick={() => setEarned(calculateEarned)}
            ></PrimaryButton>

            <Earned>{earned}</Earned>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

EDIT: Problem solved. The problem is with the `PrimaryButton` component. I tried with `button` and then function worked. Here is the `Button` component:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Btn = styled.button`
    /*some css codes*/
`

const PrimaryBtn = styled(Btn)`
    /*some special css codes for primary button*/
`

export const Button = ({ title }) => {
    return <Btn>{title}</Btn>
}

export const PrimaryButton = ({ title }) => {
    return <PrimaryBtn>{title}</PrimaryBtn>
}
```

Comment: `onClick={() => setEarned(calculateEarned())}`. You're not calling `calculateEarned` so you're not returning anything from it.

Comment: Any warnings, error in console? Also try to use `button` instead `PrimaryButton` for test
EDIT: Andy be right, you must call `calculateEarned()`

Comment: @Andy Tried but nothing changed.

Comment: @AndrewF PrimaryButton is another component. Actually it is a button. WOW, it worked. I stopped to use my button component and tried `button` and then it worked. Why is that happening?

Comment: @yusufcode when you wraped  `PrimaryBtn` you missed all inner paramaters and handlers.  `onClick` in ` PrimaryButton` does not  fire on `PrimaryBtn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `onClick` prop to `Button` component and then it started to act like a button. So, problem solved!

```
export const Button = ({ title, onClick }) => {
    return <Btn onClick={onClick}>{title}</Btn>
}

export const PrimaryButton = ({ title, onClick }) => {
    return <PrimaryBtn onClick={onClick}>{title}</PrimaryBtn>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call your function correct way.
`setEarned(calculateEarned())` instead of `setEarned(calculateEarned)`

Example :

```
export const CryptoCalculator = () => {
    const [earned, setEarned] = useState(0)

    function calculateEarned() {
        console.log('hit')
        return 1
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <PrimaryButton
                title="Calculate"
                onClick={() => setEarned(calculateEarned())}
            ></PrimaryButton>

            <Earned>{earned}</Earned>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: The problem is not about the parentheses, it's about the `PrimaryButton` component. I changed it to `button` and worked.